# Object of class DateTime error when i export data to excel

Tags: php, excel, export-to-csv, sqlsrv, sql-server-2012-express

I have a table which contain many columns. Some column contain numerical value, some contain text while some contain date.

When i try to export data to Excel, the numerical and value can be exported however when i want to export date data, it shows me this error "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string".

My export function works in such a way that user can select which column they wan to export from SQL to excel through PHP. My column are stored in array. Below is my code:

```
   //Get list of selected column from selected checkboxes
    $colarray = $_GET['colarray'];

    //convert string to array 
    $string1 = ['[',']'];
    $string2 = ["",""];
    $newcolarray = str_replace($string1, $string2, $colarray);
    $newarray = explode(",",$newcolarray);

    $filename = "File name " . date('d-M-y') . ".csv"; // Create file name

    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

//Insert column name in first row of excel
    fputcsv($f, $newarray);

    //dynamic Select query statement
    $query = "SELECT "; 
    $query .= $colarray;
    $query .= " FROM OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL"; // Get data from Database from OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL table
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

/**how can i place this code $row['Date']->format('d M Y') here***/ 
        fputcsv($f, $row);

    }

    //move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);

    //set headers to download file rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    //output all remaining data on a file pointer
    fpassthru($f);
```

Can anyone help how i can convert my date data into a string since my columns are stored in array for exporting to csv?

Comment: Where you have your comment, just put `$row['Date'] = $row['Date']->format('d M Y');`

Comment: @Nick this definitely won't work, i have to declare a variable $date = $row['Date']->format('d M Y') but where do i place the $date since I'm inserting array into my csv and the array is dependent on the selected columns.

Comment: What I am saying is replace the `DateTime` object in `$row['Date']` with the string representation of that date. I don't understand why that won't work?

Comment: @Nick I'm extremely sorry. I misunderstood your first comment. It works now. Very sorry

Comment: No problem at all. I'm glad you've got it working.

Comment: @Nick another problem on top of this. after converting the date, it appears as a different format in excel when exported. I convert this date format $row['Date'] = $row['Date']->format('M-y') but Excel is showing this format '19-Oct' and it changes my raw data from '2019-10-01' to '2019-10-19'. Why is this happening?

Comment: You should probably use the full format date i.e. `$row['Date']->format('Y-m-d')` Excel should parse that properly

Answer (score 0):

With PHP Driver for SQL Server you may [retrieve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-date-and-time-type-as-strings-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) PHP Date and Time objects as strings or as DateTime objects using the `'ReturnDatesAsStrings'` option in the connection string or at the statement level.

If I understand your case correctly, the columns in the SQL statement are dynamic. In this case you may try to use this feature at the statement level.

```
<?php

    ...
    $query = "SELECT "; 
    $query .= $colarray;
    $query .= " FROM OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL"; // Get data from Database from OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL table
    $options = array('ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), $options);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        fputcsv($f, $row);
    }   
    ...

?>
```

Another option, of course, is to format the PHP DateTime object using `DateTime::format` method, but after you check that these values are PHP DateTime objects.

```
<?php

    ...
    $query = "SELECT "; 
    $query .= $colarray;
    $query .= " FROM OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL"; // Get data from Database from OVERALL_SUMMARY_ORIGINAL table
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            if ($value instanceof DateTime) {
                $row[$key] = $row[$key]->format('d M Y')
            }
        }
        fputcsv($f, $row);
    }   
    ...

?>
```